# Why Google Cloud Translate API crashed on Android version 5 and 6?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-translate, google-translation-api

I used the Google Cloud Translate API in my app. But in Android 5 and 6 it does not work properly and the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard shows the following types of errors. In other Android versions it works properly and only 100% of the bugs occurred on Android 5 and 6.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl$1
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateImpl.<clinit>(TranslateImpl.java:44)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions$DefaultTranslateFactory.create(TranslateOptions.java:59)
   at com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions$DefaultTranslateFactory.create(TranslateOptions.java:53)
   at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:540)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.di.NetworkModule$provideTranslateClient$translateService$2.invoke(NetworkModule.java:66)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.di.NetworkModule$provideTranslateClient$translateService$2.invoke(NetworkModule.java:62)
   at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(SynchronizedLazyImpl.java:74)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.di.NetworkModule.provideTranslateClient$lambda-0(NetworkModule.java:62)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.di.NetworkModule.provideTranslateClient(NetworkModule.java:69)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.di.NetworkModule_ProvideTranslateClientFactory.provideTranslateClient(NetworkModule_ProvideTranslateClientFactory.java:38)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.translateClient(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:239)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.access$5000(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:141)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:1146)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.translateRepository(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:906)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.access$3200(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:867)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:994)
   at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.translateViewModel(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:946)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl.access$4000(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:867)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerApp_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:1018)
   at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
   at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:69)
   at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:84)
   at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:109)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.java:54)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.java:41)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.ui.translate.TranslateFragment.<clinit>(TranslateFragment.java:108)
   at com.codeboxlk.translator.ui.translate.TranslateFragment.onViewCreated(TranslateFragment.java:175)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:501)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1266)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6943)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7326)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I've created a translation service like the following:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTranslateClient(@ApplicationContext context: Context): TranslateClient {
        val headers: Map<String, String> = ImmutableMap.of(
            "X-Android-Package", context.packageName,
            "X-Android-Cert", (context.getApplicationSignature()[0])
        )

        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        val translateService: Translate by lazy {
            TranslateOptions.newBuilder()
                .setApiKey(context.getString(R.string.path))
                .setHeaderProvider { headers }
                .build().service
        }

        return TranslateClient(context, translateService)
    }
}
```

Comment: So it works in android 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11? Maybe those 2 versions are not supported anymore. In [Android ver history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) it shows that supported android version is since 8.1. Did you use any tutorial/guide?

Comment: @PjoterS Yes, in other Android versions it works like a charm. The previous version of this app also worked well on Android 5 and 6. The problem is that it is not working now.

Comment: Have you changed anything lately? New version of android studio, java or anything else? It's your own app or you posted it on google play? Since when it stopped working?

Comment: Yes this is my own app and already published on Google Play store. I have not change my code base. But recently I updated Gradle, Kotlin & Android version. I got this error from Firebase Crashlytics dashboard. It's work properly on my OP7Pro.

Comment: Lately there was some changes on [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) Have you seen those?

Comment: The above mentioned problem resolved with com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.97.0. Recently I used version 2.0.2 and it is not working with Android 5 and 6.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please post as answer with solution and some details.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this `Community Wiki` for better visibility.

As was mentioned in the comment section by OP `@Dilanka Laksiri`, the root cause of this issue was using a newer version of `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate`.

It seems that [com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:2.0.2](https://frontbackend.com/maven/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-translate/2.0.2) is not supporting Android 5 and 6.

Solution for this issue was to use older version, [com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.97.0](https://frontbackend.com/maven/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-translate/1.97.0)

Comment: It's a good idea to post things like this to make it easier for others to find solutions quickly. Great job

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Thank you so much for taking care of this. I found the solution to this problem myself. Kindly check the comments section of the questions for more details. Also, this may not be the right solution. Because we can't stay without updating dependency in future. Someone will tell us why this is happening in the 2.0.2 version here. And he will post the right solution.